# Getting warning when trying to use SnapKit to layout UILabels in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, snapkit

I'm trying to use SnapKit to layout UILabels in a custom UITableViewCell.  If I put in this code:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.height.equalTo(104)
    }
...}
```

I get a warning:
LayoutConstraints] Changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of the contentView of a UITableViewCell is not supported and will result in undefined behavior, as this property is managed by the owning UITableViewCell.

This is my first time using SnapKit so not sure if there is a way to keep SnapKit from setting the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property?

This is just the first constraint I'm adding, but I want to layout several labels in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentView either get's it's height from `heightForRowAt` or from inner elements if you use dynamic table cells , If you want static height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 104
}
```

Comment: I added a comment in my original post as you left this answer.  I want to also use other constraints to do the layout and I'm specifically using SnapKit.

Comment: add the constraints for the items only link the top item to the top of contentView and the bottom item to it's bottom don't give it any height or width constraints

Comment: I have 4 labels to layout.  Are you saying to lay them out without assigning any height or widths?

Comment: i mean don't give width/height constraints to the contentView not to subviews  ,  you're free to give items inside it a width/height but remember labels have intrinsiccontentsize which means you don't have to give them width/height , but this mainly dependent on the design

Comment: I think this comment is really the answer.  Maybe you can change your answer.  Thanks.